# How do I compile C# compatible with win server 2003 under VS12 (xxxx.exe is not a valid win32 application)

Tags: c#, winapi, compilation

I have a C# project in VS12/WIN7 but when I try to run it under windows server 2003, it throws an error that it's not a valid WIN32 application. I have tried many configuration, also changed to Any Cpu from Configuration Manager, but it won't work.
This project has some socket and threading code...
How do I fix it ?

Comment: Did you enusre the bitness? i.e your exe is not 64bit when you run it in 32 bit machine?

Comment: Yes, both Win7 and Server are 32bit version.this is the error when i try 64bit on server "the image file xxxx.exe is valid, but is for a machine type other then current machine."

Comment: So you mean you're trying to execute 64 bit application in 32 bit OS?

Comment: No, I just want to indicate i'm not runing 64 on 32 bit, anyway, `Editbin` solved this error, I also changed .net target on VS12 to .net3.5, but the problem still persist, I don't know what to do,i have installed .net3.5 on server when I execute the program nothing happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the comments to Ben's answer, you are targeting .net 4.5. This is your problem. The issue is that .net 4.5 [is not supported on Windows Server 2003](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Since you need to target Server 2003, you need to target a .net version that supports that OS. The [highest .net version to support Server 2003 is .net 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

So you should change the project settings in Visual Studio to target .net 4. This [MSDN article describes how to do that in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx). In summary you open the projet properties, navigate to the Application page, and set the target framework drop down.

Comment: Very nice of you to downvote for information which was not part of the question...You are answering a question which was not asked.

Comment: @BenVoigt editbin is never the answer here. As I said in my comment to your answer, the solution has to be to make the compiler write those PE fields. In any case, what other reason could there be for VS writing > 5.01 into the PE version fields? Can only be .net 4.5. In other words, to write your answer you already had enough info to deduce .net 4.5.

Comment: Editbin was the answer though. Before he had an application that wouldn't even try to start. Now he has an application that aborts initialization with an extremely useful error message. How can you not consider that an improvement? He now has a new followup question, but of course we won't tell him to ask it add a separate question because it would be a duplicate.

Comment: In fact there is no valid reason for csc to write a later OS version into the PE header. It is supposed to report when the prerequisite version of. NET is missing from the system. Because of a bug in writing the PE header it failed to do that.

Comment: Try creating a config file for the executable to specify exactly what you want. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9w519wzk(v=vs.100).aspx  If the executable is called x.exe, the config file must be called x.exe.config

Comment: yes, That solution worked great,Ben's answer caused me to find out that the project need to target another .net framework, and this is the solution. TY guys(.net 4 worked . older not)

Comment: Older than .net 4 should work if the runtime is installed on the target machine.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no bit-ness problem as mentioned in OP then you must check to which .NET version targeting your project and try to install appropriate version on Windows server 2003. Or target (if it is possible) to the version of .NET which is available on Windows server 2003 machine.

Comment: I guess it will show some other error when you don't have target FW version. This error is most likely to happen when you run 64 bit app in 32 bit machine

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, have you tried to run .net application built under .NET 4.5 on WinXP or Win2K3?

Answer (score -1):

Try using `editbin` to change the minimum required OS version.  That should fix the image-not-recognized issue; but you may run into other problems later.

For example:

```
EDITBIN myapp.exe /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS,5.01 /OSVERSION:5.1
```

Note: This doesn't address the root cause, so it shouldn't be treated as a final solution.  It is, however, the best way to determine whether the failure is caused by the "minimum required OS" field in the executable header.  Also, by continuing past that check to the actual startup code of the process, it may uncover the reason that the executable was marked to require a particular Windows version.

---

Really, it is a bad idea for any toolchain to use the "minimum required OS" field, because the defacto meaning of that field is "display a message about an invalid image".  And the number of deployed copies of Windows versions up to and including XP effectively make it impossible to restore the intended meaning (it's not feasible to patch all of them with a better error message).

A version check and meaningful error message during application startup is far better.

Comment: That's worked,but now it throws an error that u need to install .net framework 4.5 and it's impossible due to windows 2003.how do i change VS2012 to use older .net framework ?

Comment: -1 I think this is missing the point. The right solution is to make the compiler produce an executable with appropriate PE flags.

Comment: And the right answer will target the right framework that will function on server 2003.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I feel that this answer is USEFUL.  And the OP said as much in his comments.  Does my edit sufficiently address your concerns?